# Creating indexes on columns where primary key or unique key constraints already present

Tags: sql, oracle, database-indexes

I am currently learning indexes in Oracle. 
In Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_in.htm), following can be found :

> Although the database creates an index for you on a column with an integrity constraint, explicitly creating an index on such a column is recommended.

Can anybody here tell me the rationale behind this ?
If database creates an index automatically, why should we create another index on those columns explicitly ?

Comment: Good question.  I would expect a "not recommended" in that sentence.  Perhaps Oracle only creates the index once, and it is recommended in case the integrity constraint changes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - keeping the index when the constraints change is a good reason; however, for that very purpose, Oracle has the `KEEP INDEX` option when disabling constraints.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, if you create an index explicitly, you can give it a meaningful name. If you then need to refer to the index by name, it will be in a human-readable form.

Note that you can create an explicit index WHILE you are creating the constraint, in the `USING INDEX` clause. The documentation has a few examples: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11725

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have is those automatically created indexes got some weird names either generated as `SYS%` or inheriting names from constraint name. It is probably better to keep some naming convention for indexes

Comment: There are other differences - you can control storage, etc. with explicit index creation. Not so when the system does it for you.